# How to gzip compress a directory in hdfs without changing the name of the files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming, bigdata

I need to gzip compress a directory which will have many files. As i cant modify the file name of the files inside the directory i cant use mapreduce. Is there any way using java interface we can compress a directory without changing the names of the files inside the directory.

Comment: Why u cannot use MR jobs after changing file names ? the input of a MR job is just the directory not the file names !

Comment: Because once i compress using the MR job the filenames will not be retained and also i have a constraint that each file should not exceed more than 50 mb which i have handled using multipleoutputformater . Now the output is ready as required with the file name and size and i just need to compress the directory without changing the filenames and also the structure